# Text under icons is left aligned in windows explorer only in user main folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

I've been having this problem for months now on Windows 10 1803, but I was wondering whether someone would know how to fix it: the text under the icon in icon view in windows explorer is left aligned instead of centered. The problem is only showing up in user folder though.

[image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rdVw.png)
(cartella utente = user main folder; cartella normale = standard folder)

I've already tried resetting folder views but nothing changed.

The only way I found to fix the problem is the script I found [here](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-fix-text-in-files-and-folders-names-aligned-to-the-left-instead-of-center/) but it has the downside of disabling the free hard disk space viewer in "This PC" folder.

Is there any way to solve this problem without creating additional mess?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my very bad English.

-- Giovanni